# Python DataFrame Transform Rows to Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv that stores information about a particular object and Date.

```
Device  Date        Category    Amount
Pen     01/01/2014  A           12
Pen     01/01/2014  B           42
Pen     01/01/2014  C           10
Pen     01/01/2014  D           5
Pen     02/01/2014  A           7
Pen     02/01/2014  B           52
Pen     02/01/2014  C           1
Pen     02/01/2014  D           7
Pencil  01/01/2014  A           22
Pencil  01/01/2014  B           42
Pencil  01/01/2014  C           70
Pencil  01/01/2014  D           8
```

I want to read it into a DataFrame and make Category a column and Amounts for a specific device and date a row. This will make the dataset much smaller.

```
Device  Date        A   B   C   D
Pen    01/01/2014   12  42  10  5
Pen    02/01/2014   7   52  1   7
Pencil  01/01/2014  22  42  70  8
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python, pandas, dataframe, rows to columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492251/python-pandas-dataframe-rows-to-columns)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas transposition inside dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116600/pandas-transposition-inside-dataframe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `pivot_table` where columns that you want to keep are set as `index`, columns that go to the header are set as `columns` and columns that fill the cells in the output data frame are set as `values`:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Device', 'Date'], columns='Category', values='Amount').reset_index()

# Category  Device        Date     A     B   C  D
#        0     Pen  01/01/2014    12    42  10  5
#        1     Pen  02/01/2014     7    52   1  7
#        2  Pencil  01/01/2014    22    42  70  8
```

Answer (score 2):

using `groupby` and `unstack`

```
df.groupby(['Device', 'Date', 'Category'])['Amount'].sum().unstack().reset_index()
```

[image]